# JavaFX Character Comparator for TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx, character, comparator, tablecolumn

any idea why my comparator is not comparing? And it never goes into one of my if-statements. If I click on the column header, nothing happens.

Example characters: {'g','c','null','b','null','a'}

I want it sorted, so the null values come after the character values.

Sorted: a,b,c,g,null,null

NullComparator.java

```
package de.hhn.pp.todomanager.model;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class NullComparator implements Comparator<Character> {

    @Override
    public final int compare(final Character o1, final Character o2) {

        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
            System.out.println(
                    "If1");
            return 0;
        }

        if (o1 == null) {
            System.out.println(
                    "If2");
            return 1;
        }

        if (o2 == null) {
            System.out.println(
                    "If3");
            return -1;
        }
        System.out.println("passed the ifs");

        return o1.compareTo(o2);  //edited
    }
}
```

MainViewController.java

```
TableColumn<TaskControl, Character> colPrioritaet;
private TableView<TaskControl> tblView;


colPrioritaet
                .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priority"));
        colPrioritaet.setComparator(new NullComparator());
```

TaskControl.java

```
private char priority;
```

Comment: Your `compare` method checks for null values, but never actually compares `o1` with `o2` when both are non-null.

Comment: Thanks. Now at least something happens. Will edit my code. The comparator still never goes through one of the ifs though. Any idea why that is? Will add example values to my question and how I would like to have it sorted.